# Convert tab delimited (\t) text file to another tab delimited (\t) text file without last column in python

Tags: python-3.x, text-files, delimiter

I have a tab delimited (\t) text file with nine columns, How to get a same tab delimited (\t) text file with out last column in python

**Sample Data** (sampledata.txt)

> **col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6    col7    col8    col9**
>
> val1    val2    val3    val4    val5    val6    val7    val8    val9

**Expected Output** (expecteddata.txt)

> **col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6    col7    col8**
>
> val1    val2    val3    val4    val5    val6    val7    val8

Here tab delimiter is not visible, There is a tab space between columns and i am trying to delete last column through python code

Comment: Can you post a sample data and expected output?

Comment: Hi @Rakesh, This is the sample data and expected output, Kindly check it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, Check the below codes

> import pandas

Read text file into data frame with \t delimiter

> dataframe = pandas.read_csv('sampledata.txt',delimiter="\t")

Remove last column in dataframe

> dataframe = dataframe.iloc[:, :-1]

Write text file by \t delimiter

> dataframe.to_csv(r'expecteddata.txt', header=True, index=None, sep='\t')

Answer (score 1):

Reading directly through pandas

```
df = pandas.read_csv(filename, sep='\t', lineterminator='\r')
```

Or try using codecs - helps in speed and robustness

```
import codecs
import pandas
data = codecs.open('file','rU','UTF-16')
df = pandas.read_csv(data, sep='\t')
```

Deleting the last column

```
df = df.iloc[:, :-1]
```

Then convert back to text file

Use encoding utf-8 while writing csv and useText(tab delimiter) while saving it as text

Comment: Ya after deleting last column in data frame how to write that data frame into tab delimiter (\t) text file, That is my question. If possible kindly look into it @sai tsvv

Comment: Use encoding utf-8 while writing csv and useText(tab delimiter) while saving it as text

Comment: Now i am doing that what you said @sai tsvv, But i want python code instead of saving tab delimited text file

Comment: Thank you @sai tsvv